# What is the make and model of the watch worn by The Florist's henchman in The Town

Tags: props, the-town

In Ben Affleck's crime drama *The Town*, towards the end, Doug MacRae kills Rusty the henchman before killing the Florist.

Since the scene of Rusty hitting floor displays the watch so prominently:

I wonder what watch this is.  I have started looking into luxury watches, and it doesn't seem like one I've seen before.  I figure Rusty is doing pretty well for himself, so this must be a notable timepiece.

Thanks to any fellow watch enthusiasts out there.

[image]

Comment: Seems more like a timepiece question and not a movie question

Comment: I don't believe there is a jewelry exchange in the network.  Trivia questions are now in play, yeah?

Comment: I didn’t VTC or claim it’s off topic, just explaining my downvote. Not helpful in terms of appreciating or understanding film or television.

Comment: Is that the scope of trivia now allowed?  I didn't think there was any.

Comment: Also, clearly the director thought it was important.

Comment: Downvotes have nothing inherently to do with what’s allowed and what’s not allowed. I don’t know how to explain it any more clearly. There no rules this question violates, my downvote is not about any rules. Just because a question doesn’t break any rules doesn’t make it a good question.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger - And also important to the producers. Without product placement, a lot of Hollywood films wouldn't get made at all, or made with a lower budget

Comment: This is fine for a  movie question as the watch is in the movie.  I've never heard of a timepiece stack. lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the henchman (played by Dennis McLaughlin) is wearing a [Rolex President Day-Date Yellow Gold Green Enamel Diamond Mens Watch (118348)](https://www.swisswatchexpo.com/watches/rolex-president-day-date-yellow-gold-green-enamel-diamond-mens-watch-118348-47085/) (approx value £50,000) or a similar model.

[image]

[image]

The watch was almost certainly a product placement given that almost everyone in that film is sporting a nice watch, most of them Rolexes.

- John Hamm's FBI agent is wearing a [Rolex GMT Master Black Bezel Automatic Steel Mens Watch 16700](https://www.swisswatchexpo.com/watches/rolex-gmt-master-black-bezel-automatic-steel-mens-watch-16700-43849x/) (approx. value £14,000). The actor apparently liked it so much that he was able to keep it after filming (or bought an identical one).

> [image]

- Jeremy Renner is sporting a [Rolex President Day-Date 36mm Yellow Gold Silver Dial Watch 18038](https://www.swisswatchexpo.com/watches/rolex-president-day-date-36mm-yellow-gold-silver-dial-watch-18038-46551/) (approx. value £15,000)

> [image]

- Rebecca Hall has an [18K Gold Tank Louis Cartier](https://www.cartier.com/en-us/watches/collections/tank/tank-louis-cartier-watch-CRW1529856.html) (approx. value £12,000)

> [image]